# Macro won't stop when value in Column is empty

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I'm using below code populate a column in my main Sheet (referred to as sht in code). In this sheet (sht) i want the macro to stop when it hits an empty cell in Column C, when coming down from C85. How would i go and pursue this goal?

```
Sub VTZ()

Dim sht As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet
Set sht = Sheets("16-Compliancy-Rebuild")
Set sht2 = Sheets("OpmerkingBackup")
Dim Table1 As Range
Dim Table2 As Range
Dim Dept_Row As Long
Dim Dept_Clm As Long
Dim rng As Range
Set Table1 = sht.Range("D85:D1185")
Set Table2 = sht2.Range("B3:B1103")
Dept_Row = sht.Range("H85").Row
Dept_Clm = sht.Range("H85").Column
For Each cl In Table1
Set rng = Table2.Find(cl, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookAt:=xlWhole)
If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    sht.Cells(Dept_Row, Dept_Clm) = sht2.Cells(rng.Row, 6).Value
End If
Dept_Row = Dept_Row + 1
Next cl
MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

Tried alot of Googling on forehand and can't seem to find the right way to do this.

Comment: You're talking about column C, but your macro doesn't touch column C at all. Can you provide more information about your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating this part...

```
For Each cl In Table1.cells
Set rng = Table2.Find(cl, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookAt:=xlWhole)
If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    sht.Cells(Dept_Row, Dept_Clm) = sht2.Cells(rng.Row, 6).Value
else
Exit For 'exits the loop

End If
Dept_Row = Dept_Row + 1
Next cl
```

I'm not sure if that's the right part you want to exit the loop. Another way would just be...

```
For Each cl In Table1.cells
If Isempty(cl) then
    Exit Sub 'this completely exits the macro
Endif
Set rng = Table2.Find(cl, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookAt:=xlWhole)
If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    sht.Cells(Dept_Row, Dept_Clm) = sht2.Cells(rng.Row, 6).Value

End If
Dept_Row = Dept_Row + 1
Next cl
```

Comment: Your last code worked perfect. Thanks for your ninja-edit, and great help. Cheers to you.